# How to show stacktrace in django-debug-toolbar

Tags: django-debug-toolbar

How can I force ddt to show me stacktrace? I can only see parts of templates in which queries are executed. But there are no views which generates queries. I set

```
'ENABLE_STACKTRACES' : True
```

in settings but this does not help me. I have version 0.9.4.

Comment: I have the same problem after upgrading to DDT 0.9.4. I upgraded because Django 1.4 had some incompatibilities with 0.8.x. The stacktraces are what I use the toolbar the most to find where I can reduce queries.

Answer (score 1):

Allow myself to quote... [myself](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar/issues/272#issuecomment-5094725):

> You can patch your 0.9.4 install by changing debug_toolbar/panels/sql.py:197 to read
>
> ```
> params = map(escape, os.path.split(frame[0]) + frame[1:])
> ```
>
> (and `import os.path` somewhere above).
>
> It looks like this issue was fixed in [12fdf7e](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar/commit/12fdf7ea605d3716d6c9127e22a63bcc345d55be) (`render_stacktrace`).