# django-debug-toolbar. Can I view stacktrace from views.py?

Tags: django, django-debug-toolbar

In the past I remember I could see the python stacktrace in `django-debug-toolbar`. Having just installed it in my new PC (running django 1.4) I can only see the sql query and the template context.

This is my configuration:

```
DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PANELS = (
    'debug_toolbar.panels.version.VersionDebugPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.timer.TimerDebugPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.settings_vars.SettingsVarsDebugPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.headers.HeaderDebugPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.request_vars.RequestVarsDebugPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.template.TemplateDebugPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.sql.SQLDebugPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.signals.SignalDebugPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.logger.LoggingPanel',
)


DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
    'INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS': True,
    'ENABLE_STACKTRACES' : True,
    'HIDE_DJANGO_SQL': False,
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe the HTML is there but CSS hides it .... An alternative is to install django-extensions and werkzeug, then use runserver_plus.

Comment: thanks. I tried to find any hidden html but I couldn't. Are django-extensions and wekzeug complimentary to django-debug-toolbar or are they completely different profiling tools?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a version <= 0.9.4? If so, this is a [known issue](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar/issues/272#issuecomment-5094725).

You can manually patch your 0.9.4 install by following the instructions on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352158/how-to-show-stacktrace-in-django-debug-toolbar), or simply upgrade to a more recent version.